# Structure <verb> 一 <verb>

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure

I met with a structure of this type many times during last days, so I wonder:

> What is the meaning of "[verb] 一 [verb]"?

For instance:

- 想一想
- 看一看
- 等一等

Comment: search this site, find many relevant/pertinent answers

Comment: for previous discussions of this topic, search Q&A using "看一看＂and also see answer by user6065 (quotation from 外国人实用汉语语法) in
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/10046/why-does-the-%E8%AF%B7-take-two-duplicate-words-on-its-verb-occasionally-e-g-%E8%AF%B7%E6%B4%97%E6%B4%97%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84%E8%A2%9C/10047#10047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "for a moment", in other words, doing the action for a short time only.

讓我看一看 ==> Let me see(for a moment).
你可以想一想 ==> You may think(for a moment).

It is often used as suggestion to the speaker with mild imperative.

看一看吧！ ==> Just look(for a moment)!

Answer (score 2):

Duplication of words is very common in Chinese. It doesn't have much grammatical meaning but it adds a little emphasis.

Sometimes, especially for Chinese spoken in Singapore (my native tongue), the order [verb][verb][particle] is used more often for better cohesion.

For example: 
让我想想一下吧! （Usually 让我想一想吧!）--> Please let me think for a moment.
你的伤这么严重，让我看看！(Usually 你的伤这么严重，让我看一看!) --> Your injury is very serious, let me see.